# Куки уходят, но скрипт не работает

Tags: cookie, javascript

Отправляю куки таким образом, не могу сказать правильно ли делаю, но в куки информация отправляется, но идея в том что бы это всплывающее окно не появлялось пока живы куки, а оно всё равно появляется, подскажите в чём дело.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('_visited=1') == -1) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sliderBox').slideTo({
            transition: 300,
            top: 'center',
            left: 'center',
            inside: window
        });
        $('#background').height($(document).height());

        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
            $('#sliderBox').stop().slideTo({
                transition: 300,
                top: 'center',
                left: 'center',
                inside: window
            });
        });

        var closeWelcomeBox;

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if (!closeWelcomeBox) {
                $('#sliderBox').stop().slideTo({
                    transition: 300,
                    top: 'center',
                    left: 'center',
                    inside: window
                });
            }
        });

        $("#closeWelcomeBox").click(function() {
            $('#sliderBox').stop().slideTo({
                transition: 500,
                top: -400
            });
            $('#background').fadeOut(500);
            closeWelcomeBox = true;
        });
    });
    document.cookie = '_visited=1; path=/';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще тебе проверять куки после загрузки документа. То есть так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('_visited=1') == -1) {
    ...
    }
});
```

А то у тебя получается, что загрузка документа только началась, а скрипт уже сработал, и в результате у тебя ничего не получается.